# jquery ajax action when there is no error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I do not understand what is off with my logic. I have a typical form that I use ajax to submit the data.

```
$('#contactForm').on('submit',function(e){
    var formMsg = $('#contactFormReturnMsg');
    formMsg.empty();
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('contact.php', $('#contactForm').serialize(),function(data){
        if(data.error){
            formMsg.append(data.error);
        }else{
            formMsg.append("Email received!");  
        }
    },"json");
});
```

When I have an error, I get the error msgs appended correctly. If I don't have an error, I do not see the else statement run through. Why is this?

Comment: Are there any console errors?

Comment: No errors. Console log within the else{} also does not show.

Comment: Post the content of data when data.error does not exist

Comment: Well I suppose I will get no data content because on my php side, the only echo I have is for errors. ie: echo json_encode($error); I realize I can resolve this by sending a success msg from PHP, but I don't get why I need to.

Comment: You should always return a value, for example success: true/false. Then you could check if data.success = false, show data.error

Comment: I will do that if it is the only way. But can you explain why I don't go to the else{} ?